# How to override the email structure

Tags: 8, emails

I have a problem with Drupal 8. I have enabled the default contact form and I have added two custom fields.
Currently, the form send a mail with my two fields at the end of the mail. I want to change that order but I don't know what to do.

I have used a custom submit thanks to that line in my form alter.

```
$form ['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'module_contact_submit';
```

But now I am lost and I don't know what to do in my submit function. Maybe there is a twig template for the mail?

Thank you for reading this and helping.